# How to parse json field like a:[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9]] using scala?

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I want parse one of field in Json format its like this

"{a:[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]}"

In the above field 'a' want to extract first two digits 
I tried with List[Int] in scala its not working. Try extract first two digits in each set like this

a1:1

a2:2

Comment: Are you using a JSON library to handle the data? If so, which one are you using?

Comment: and what generated this? Because it is not JSON.

Comment: Are you using any Json library? If not try using sprayJson

Comment: Please provide a proper json or provide some more clarification on the question.

Comment: I used play.api.libs.json

Answer (score 1):

> "{a:[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]}"

This is not valid JSON.

```
{
    "a": [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ]
}
```

**a** needs to be in double-quotes.

Edit: If this is the value of a field in Json, then it is an object with a field "a" that is a List[List[Int]].

Comment: I am using correct Json format. It is one of the field in Json. I used play.api.libs.json._

Comment: I just want to know what should be the data type can handle to extract the Integers